# Deploy Database From C# To Sql Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database

I am looking for some **.Net** code sample or any **.Net** library using which I would like to build a small tool to automate my activities like I  can connect to Sql Azure . Once I get connected I would like to deploy my database(mdf & ldf file) to the remote sql azure server .Once the deployment gets completed I would like to create a login and respective user for the deployed databases and assign them required permissions respective to databases . Currently I am doing all these activities from Management Studio but I want to create a tool which would does all these activities on a click of button . I would define a step by step template for all my activities and this tool will execute each step .

I tried looking for libraries but didn't find anything useful . Now I have no idea where to start so Please help me as I am a novice to these type of stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does all of this via its Database Project template. It will either update the target directly, or generate a script which you can execute. Also remember the OSQL command line version of Management Studio for doing batch script execution.

Comment: sure I will explore Database Project template if that can help me

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution in this case will be to use Visual Studio Release Management.
In Release Manager you can create workflow to execute Deployment Tasks. If you have a Database project which produces a DACPAC, you can use Azure SQL Database Deployment task in Release Manager to deploy the Database to SQL Azure. More Details can be found here

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/azure-web-apps-and-sql-db

Answer (score -1):

With Azure, you can't just copy the local mdf file.  If you need to migrate schema and data, the easiest way to migration from local Sql Server to Azure, is to export the database to a BACPAC file, and then import that file back into azure. [migrate bacppac file](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-import-bacpac-ssms/).

After you've create your database and populated, use the Azure portal or Sql Management studio to create additional logins.

Comment: Thanks . Right now I am doing all these using Sql Management Studio as you explained .I am using Task->Deploy Database To Microsoft Sql Azure. I am looking for one click solution to avoid performing these multiple steps .

Comment: @GaryHolland As mention  Is there any .net library or some other tool which automate this operation. i.e creating database on azure server through code.